# Create outgoing queue in windows server 2008

Tags: c#, msmq

This is rather a stupid question. But I couldn't find a good post regarding this.I want to create a queue in Outgoing queue in MSMQ.
I have a task to get all the Outgoing queues in the machine and clear the messages if it matches to a criteria.

Can anybody give an idea how to create an Outgoing queue in Windows server 2008 machine.

Comment: Send a message to a machine that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "create" an outgoing queue.

When you send a message to a queue the MSMQ sub-system first writes the message to a local, temporary, outgoing queue before transmitting the message to the destination queue. The lifespan of the temporary outgoing queue is controlled by the MSMQ sub-system and not the developer.

This is because MSMQ uses a [*store and forward*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Store_and_forward) model to transmit messages around.

John Breakwell talks about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/11/12/how-do-i-create-an-msmq-outgoing-queue.aspx).

However, you can address the outgoing queues in the same way you would address the remote queue which you are sending to, but setting a flag called `MQ_ADMIN_ACCESS`.

This technique is described [here](http://www.yortondotnet.com/2010/04/accessing-outgoing-message-queues-with.html).